# Do I need to own an iPhone to get a signing key? (or: Can I build my Phonegap App without owning an iPhone?)

Tags: iphone, cordova, dreamweaver

I am hoping to be able to build an iPhone app using Phonegap. I have already built the entire site and I am at the stage where I simply want to be able to make a build that I can put on an actual iPhone device and test it out.

Long story short, I am trying to use Dreamweaver, which now supports Phonegap, to make that build.

I borrowed a friend's Macbook Air, and signed up for an Apple developer licence, and paid my 100 dollar yearly fee. I think I'm good to go as far as Apple agreements go.

However, in the instructions for building with Phonegap in Dreamweaver, it seems that I have to have something called a "signing key", and it also seems like whatever this key is, it's tied to a device.

I don't own any Apple devices myself, and I'm just a lone developer without a budget to go out and buy Apple devices as needed. My hope was that I could make my app available on iTunes, have my friends who own Apple devices download it, and have them help me beta test my app that way.

Am I right in my understanding that this "signing key" requires a device?

How do I go about jumping through all of Apple's hoops when I don't own an Apple device myself? I have a Macbook Air laptop I can borrow now and again, and if I borrow a friend's iPhone, I can only hold onto it for as long as they're willing to stand beside me and let me muck about with it. It is, after all, their phone.

Comment: Dave, did you ever find a way to test your Phonegap app on an iPhone easily? I've got the same problem as you!

Comment: @MagnusSmith: If you're using Phonegap, it is entirely possible to *develop* without an iPhone, but one needs an iPhone (or iPad) to do real *testing*. I've managed to get by with using friends phones when I'm ready to test, as well as having friends do beta testing for me. Once you have a signing key from their phone, you can email them the app and have them install it without you present, then report back on what it is you need them to test.

Comment: Thanks for responding. So if I get a key, I just need to email the IPA file? You make it sound easy! For anyone else with this issue; I've added a new question too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750228/test-phonegap-build-app-on-a-friends-iphone/13750655#13750655

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You do not need to own any Apple product to have a 'signing key'. But you need to have an IOS computer to develop your application. Also it is not possible to put the application to store or to install it to an apple device without signing it with the key.

Answer (score 0):

One option is [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/), a service that can compile your app for you.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I was under the impression that one had to use Dreamweaver to use the Phonegap Build service. If not, that would be great.

Comment: Even if you use phonegap, you'll still need a signing key to build a valid application.

Comment: so you do NOT build if you do not pay 100 bucks per year to Apple, am I right?