# Test Phonegap Build app on a friend's iPhone

Tags: iphone, testing, cordova

I have created a mobile app using **Phonegap Build** (not just Phonegap...but [Build](http://build.phonegap.com)). I have a Windows PC and do not use eclipse or xcode. I just write the Javascript and let Build do all the complex stuff for me.

I can easily test my app on an Android device by scanning the QR code that is displayed on the Build page after my app compiles....but **how can I test on an iPhone or iPad?** I can convince a family member to loan me one for a day, but I don't have a Mac (I could probably visit another friend to use one, briefly).

It would not be appropriate at this point to spend $99 on a developer certificate, even though this app may be submitted to the store eventually. If $99 is the only option, I would be grateful to anyone who makes this clear!

Or perhaps I just need to learn about [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) or [Lesspainful](https://www.lesspainful.com/)? The descriptions are confusing me at present, but I will try harder if I hear some experts tell me that this is the right way to go!

It would be good to test on a real Apple device, as I haven't had much luck getting an emulator going...but perhaps the only answer to my dilemma is to tell me to stick with emulators. (In which case: is there a nice step-by-step tutorial for a complete beginner to install an iPhone emulator in **Windows**?).

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to test on a device, your app needs to be signed using your certificate. You'll also need a development provision profile that includes the device ID's of any devices you want to test on. In order to get those things, you need to join Apple's iOS developer program. This is true even if you're using the PhoneGap Build service; in order to build for a device, you need to upload your certificate and provision profile to PhoneGap Build. Look at PhoneGap Build's [Building for iOS](http://build.phonegap.com/docs/ios-builds) page for complete information. **All this means that you'll need to pay the $99 fee to join the iOS Developer Program.**

An alternative is to jailbreak your device (or, in this case, your friend's device). You can find instructions for that on the web if you're so inclined. However, I don't think you'll be able to build through PhoneGap Build in that case -- you'll need to build your app yourself with Xcode or possibly some other set of tools.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I think paying $99 sounds nicer than learning how to set up xcode, so we will do that (after we've submitted to the Google Play store and proved to ourselves we are fully ready!). Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Just as an update for anyone else that ends up here. You can now use [Adobe PhoneGap Developer App](http://app.phonegap.com/) which allows you to run the Apps on devices without ID's, licenses etc. [Here is a guide to getting started](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/23/phonegap-developer-app/).

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks good, but I wish they'd write a guide for people who don't use command line tool (i.e. anyone who enjoys the simplicity of Build)!

Comment: FYI: this answer used to be true. Apple sadly took the Adobe PhoneGap Developer App out of the AppStore: https://blog.phonegap.com/update-on-the-phonegap-developer-app-ios-99e07e3309dd

It sounds like this might change in the future again.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to join the Apple Developer Program to be able to sign the build and create the .IPA to use TestFlight or other methods to get the build onto the device.

There are options for you to test on a device without that though - see [App.io](https://app.io/) for an in-browser emulator.

Whether you go with that or TestFlight I've blogged about [Getting mobile app builds to your customers](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2013/04/02/getting-mobile-app-builds-to-your-customers/) which includes the pros and cons of the options and the steps you'd need to go through.

Answer (score 0):

install iTune on your windows PC. Copy IPA file to application directory of iTune. When connecting device (iPhone,iPad or iPod), sync apps. Then you can test on real device.

Comment: Thanks. Is it really that simple? Trouble is...I don't think Phonegap Build offers the IPA download until you upload a certificate?

Comment: @MagnusSmith Exactly. Even if they could provide an .ipa file, it wouldn't run on a non-jailbroken device without having been signed with a valid certificate. The page I linked in my answer says: *Once your key is added, we'll attempt to rebuild the application for iOS. If all goes well, you should see a link for the built ipa file available.*